# Do we need intersubjective agreement for social knowledge?

Tags: belief

Do we need intersubjective agreement for social knowledge? Suppose I have two photographs, and I am fairly clear to myself that they are the same person, but everyone else disagrees. Do I know they are the same person? Suppose that I also think I remember something that would explain the identity, but no-one can confirm the memory. Should I believe in that explanation and what follows from it?

What if the explanation posits a lot of unusual events that no-one confirms and that have little to no evidence for them? Should I believe whatever seems like the best explanation, even if it is improbable? Do I *know* that this explanation is what occurred?

Comment: At the outset, knowledge does not imply truth. A person's knowledge might be simply inaccurate. Other than that, there are a few gaps that require us to speculate in order to address your epistemological question. It is unclear what knowledge is of "social" type. Is the explanation for the identity purely empirical? does the person who posits the identity have any history of delusion, memory deterioration, or other impairment?

Comment: that's fair thanks @IñakiViggers